Error less observations than random effects in lmer with time varying covariate
I am running a multilevel growth curve model to examine predictors of social anhedonia (SA) trajectory through ages 12, 15 and 18. SA is a continuous numeric variable. The age variable (Index1) has been coded as 0 for age 12, 1 for age 15 and 2 for age 18. I am currently using a time varying predictor, stress (LSI), which was measured at ages 12, 15 and 18, to examine whether trajectory/variation in LSI predicts difference in SA trajectory. LSI is a continuous numeric variable and was grand-mean centered before using in the models. The data has been converted to long format with SA in 1 column, LSI in the other, ID in another, and age in another column. I used the code below to run my model using lmer. However, I get the following error. Please let me know how I can solve this error. Please note that I have 50% missing data in SA at age 12, which I am handling using the REML method.
The model syntax:
modelLSI_maineff_RE <- lmer(SA ~ Index1* LSI+ (1 + Index1+LSI |ID), data = LSIDATA, control = lmerControl(optimizer ="bobyqa"), REML=TRUE) summary(modelLSI_maineff_RE)

The error:
 Error: number of observations (=1080) <= number of random effects (=1479) for term (1 + Index1 + LSI | ID); the random-effects parameters and the residual variance (or scale parameter) are probably unidentifiable

I did test the within-person variance for the LSI variable and the within-person variance is significant from the Greenhouse-Geisser, Hyunh-Feidt tests.
I also tried control = lmerControl(check.nobs.vs.nRE = "ignore") like so:
modelLSI_maineff_RE <- lmer(SA ~ Index1* LSI+ (1 + Index1+LSI |ID), data = LSIDATA, control = lmerControl(check.nobs.vs.nRE = "ignore", optimizer ="bobyqa", check.conv.singular = .makeCC(action = "ignore", tol = 1e-4)), REML=TRUE)

The full output can be seen below:
summary(modelLSI_maineff_RE)
Linear mixed model fit by REML. t-tests use Satterthwaite's method ['lmerModLmerTest']
Formula: SA ~ Index1 * LSI + (1 + Index1 + LSI | ID)
Data: LSIDATA
Control: lmerControl(check.nobs.vs.nRE = "ignore", optimizer = "bobyqa",
check.conv.singular = .makeCC(action = "ignore", tol = 1e-04))

REML criterion at convergence: 7299.6

Scaled residuals:
Min 1Q Median 3Q Max
-2.7289 -0.4832 -0.1449 0.3604 4.5715

Random effects:
Groups Name Variance Std.Dev. Corr
ID (Intercept) 30.2919 5.5038
Index1 2.4765 1.5737 -0.15
LSI 0.1669 0.4085 -0.23 0.70
Residual 24.1793 4.9172
Number of obs: 1080, groups: ID, 493

Fixed effects:
Estimate Std. Error df t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) 24.68016 0.39722 313.43436 62.133 < 2e-16 ***
Index1 0.98495 0.23626 362.75018 4.169 3.83e-05 ***
LSI -0.05197 0.06226 273.85575 -0.835 0.4046
Index1:LSI 0.09797 0.04506 426.01185 2.174 0.0302 *
Signif. codes: 0 ‘’ 0.001 ‘’ 0.01 ‘’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
(Intr) Index1 LSI
Index1 -0.645
LSI -0.032 0.057
Index1:LSI 0.015 0.037 -0.695

I am a little wary of the outputs still, as the error states that I have equal observations as the number of random effects (i.e., 3 observations per ID and 3 random effects). Hence, I am wondering whether I can simplify the model as either of the below models and choose the one with the best-fit statistics:
modelLSI2 <- lmer(SA ~ Index1* LSI+ (1 |ID)+  (Index1+LSI -1|ID),data = LSIDATA, control = lmerControl(optimizer ="bobyqa"), REML=TRUE)
              OR
modelLSI3 <- lmer(SA ~ Index1* LSI+ (1+LSI |ID),data = LSIDATA, control = lmerControl(optimizer ="bobyqa"), REML=TRUE)

Example of dataset:


Welcome to CV! What does the ID variable here signify? Also its seems your model output was messed up somehow when you copied it to here. I would fix that and edit it into your question so it is more easy to read. One can guess what is being said here if you are familiar with lme4, but it still diverts people away from answering if it takes too long to read.

This has been cross-posted to r-sig-mixed-models@r-project.org. Please pick a single venue to start with.
